# How to modify a TSQL Replace table function for my case?

Tags: function, t-sql

I am using SSMS 2008 and I have the following Table function to take a text string and remove all metatags from Microsoft Word.  The tags are enclosed in "<...>" and there can be any number of tags / record in one column.

I created this table function to update each row in this column.

```
alter function dbo.ufn_StripHTML
    (   @Input      varchar(8000),
        @Delimiter  char(1)
    )
returns varchar(8000)
as

begin

    declare @Output varchar(8000)
    select  @Input = replace(replace(@input, '<', @Delimiter), '>', @Delimiter)

    select @Output = isnull(@Output, '') + s
    from    (    select   row_number() over (order by n.id asc) [i],
                 substring(@Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.id + 1, charindex(@Delimiter, @Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.id + 1) - n.id - 1) [s]
            from    [evolv_cs].[dbo].[progress_note] n
            where   n.id = charindex(@Delimiter, @Delimiter + @Input + @Delimiter, n.id) and
                 n.id <= len(@Delimiter + @Input)
            ) d
    where i % 2 = 1

    return @Output

end
```

This table function would work if [progress_note] had an "id" int column.  But it does not and I cannot modify this table either, by adding an int column.  So the problem is that I am trying to use this function on a temp table.

So I tried creating a view based on this table and then adding a PK int column to it.  Because when I tried to create the view with this additional PK int column ("id"), it gave me an error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.
```

But ALTER VIEW does not support adding columns.  Is there another way to do this?  Here is my original temp table I am trying to modify:

```
select [progress_note].[note_text], [progress_note].[event_log_id]
INTO #TEMP_PN
from [evolv_cs].[dbo].[progress_note]
group by [progress_note].[event_log_id], [progress_note].[note_text]
```

[note_text] is varchar(max) and event_log_id is uniqueidentifier.  So [note_text] contains a bunch of "<" and ">" chars.  How can I modify this dbo.ufn_StripHTML function?

Of course, if I try to replace [progress_note] table with #TEMP_PN in the table function, it will error cause it won't recognize it.  So how can I modify this function for my case?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function a while ago to do this.  I encourage you to at least try it.

```
Create Function dbo.StripHTML(@HTML VarChar(max))
Returns VarChar(Max)
As
Begin

  While @HTML Like '%[<]%'
    Set @HTML = Stuff(@HTML, PatIndex('%[<]%', @HTML), CharIndex('>', @HTML, PatIndex('%[<]%', @HTML))-PatIndex('%[<]%', @HTML)+1, '')

  Set @HTML = Replace(@HTML, '&nbsp;', ' ')
  Set @HTML = Replace(@HTML, '&lt;', '<')
  Set @HTML = Replace(@HTML, '&gt;', '>')
  Set @HTML = Replace(@HTML, '&quot;', '"')
  Set @HTML = Replace(@HTML, '&amp;', '&')

  Return LTrim(RTrim(@HTML))
End
```

You would call the function like this:

```
Select dbo.StripHTML('<p>This is some text</p>')
```

or

```
Select dbo.StripHTML(ColumnNameHere) From TableNameHere
```

Comment: I updated the code.  There was a small copy/paste error.  I also added example usage.

Comment: Thanks G, but I am looking for a table function, not a scalar function.  Like the title of this question says.

Comment: The function in your original question is NOT a table valued function either.  It returns a varchar(8000), not a table.